# Finding path in Maze

Tags: java, puzzle, recursive-backtracking

I recently gave an interview and was asked the following question.

A maze is a group of linked Places.  Each Place has a North, South, East, and West Place adjacent to it.  There are two special pre-defined Place's:  Place Wall represents a wall - the mouse can't go there.  Place Cheese is ... cheese!   The connections between Places are symmetrical - if you start from any Place and go North and then South, you return to where you were.

To simplify things, the maze has no closed loops - that is, if you start in any Place and follow any path, you eventually either hit a wall or find cheese - you never come back to the Place you started unless you actually retrace your steps.

A mouse starts off in some Place and searches around for Cheese.  When it finds Cheese, it returns a set of directions - a string of the letters NSEW that lead from where it started to the Cheese.

The following framework defines the classes and functions.  Some other code not included here generates a maze by creating a bunch of Place's and linking them.  It then calls mouse(), passing some starting Place from the maze:

```
interface Place {

// Return the adjacent Place in the given direction
public Place goNorth();
public Place goSouth();
public Place goEast();
public Place goWest();

// Returns true only for the special "Wall" place
public bool isWall();

// Returns true only for the special "Cheese" place
public bool isCheese();
};

class Mouse {
  public Mouse() {}

  // Return a string of the letters NSEW which, if used to traverse the
  // the maze from startingPoint, will reach a Place where isCheese() is
  // true.  Return null if you can't find such a path.
  public String findCheese(Place startingPoint) {
    ... fill this in ...
  }
}
```

Implement findCheese().  You can add any fields or helper methods you need to Mouse.
Extra credit:  Eliminate the "no closed loops" restriction.  That is, change your code so that it works correctly even if there might be a path like SSNEEW that leads the mouse back to the Place it started from.

This is what  I tried. I understand this won't be the best or optimized solution, and wanted feedback as to what I else I could try. I have not considered the extra credit part

```
public String findCheese(place startingPoint)
{
    //Call helper function in all 4 directions;
    return findCheeseHelper(startingPoint,new StringBuilder("N")).append(
        findCheeseHelper(startingPoint,new StringBuilder("S"))).append(
            findCheeseHelper(startingPoint,new StringBuilder("E"))).append(
                findCheeseHelper(startingPoint,new StringBuilder("W"))).toString();
}


public StringBuilder findCheeseHelper(place startingPoint, StringBuilder direction)
{
    StringBuilder nDir=new StringBuilder("");
    StringBuilder sDir=new StringBuilder("");
    StringBuilder eDir=new StringBuilder("");
    StringBuilder wDir=new StringBuilder("");

    //Rerturn which direction this step came from if cheese found
    if(startingPoint.isCheese())
    {
        return direction;
    }
    //Specify this is not a correct direction by returning an empty String
    else if(startingPoint.isWall())
    {
        return "";
    }

    //Explore all other 3 directions (except the one this step came from)
    if(direction=="N")
    {
        sDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goSouth(), new StringBuilder("N"));
        eDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goEast(), new StringBuilder("E"));
        wDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goWest(), new StringBuilder("W"));
    }
    else if(direction=="E")
    {
        nDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goNorth(), new StringBuilder("N"));
        sDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goSouth(), new StringBuilder("S"));
        wDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goWest(), new StringBuilder("E"));
    }
    else if(direction=="W")
    {
        nDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goNorth(), new StringBuilder("N"));
        sDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goSouth(), new StringBuilder("S"));
        eDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goEast(), new StringBuilder("W"));
    }
    else if(direction=="S")
    {
        nDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goNorth(), new StringBuilder("S"));
        eDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goEast(), new StringBuilder("E"));
        wDir=findCheeseHelper(startPoint.goWest(), new StringBuilder("W"));
    }

    //If I hit wall in every direction, I will get empty string and so specify to calling 
    //function that this is not a correct direction
    if(nDir.equals("") && sDir.equals("") && eDir.equals("") && wDir.equals(""))
        return new StringBuilder("");

    //If Cheese was found in even 1 direction, return direction to come to this step, appended with the path
    // forward to the calling function
    return direction.append(nDir).append(sDir).append(eDir).append(wDir);
}
```

Comment: You may wish to look into simple [maze theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm) for ways to solve this problem. The simplest way to solve it is definitely a wall-follower, but you can try one of the more complex methods if you are feeling ambitions.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about a similar problem: Traversing a two-dimensional array freely, by cardinal direction (NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST): http://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/traverse_2d_array/ It is the *basis* on which to solve a problem like this, but specifically for when the underlying maze itself is a double-array of integers--zero being the "path", one being the "wall". It just allows you to freely move around--without any regard to walls or paths--but it is the first step. Don't know if it helps your particular problem, but perhaps it will give you a different perspective.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) discussion...